# Use C++ Template in Swift

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, templates, generics

This is my cpp template:

```
template <typename T>
class CppTemplate1
{
public:
    CppTemplate1(){}
    T Mul(T a, T b){ return a*b; }
};
```

I instantiated it in obj c:

```
@interface templatetest<__covariant T: id>()
@property CppTemplate1<T> m_temp;
@end

@implementation templatetest
- (instancetype)init {
    return self;
}

- (_Nullable id)Mult: (_Nullable id) a sec: (_Nullable id) b{
    return _m_temp.Mul(a, b);
}
@end
```

Now I want to use it in Swift:

```
let m = templatetest<Int>()
let s = m?.mult(3, sec: 5)
print(s)
```

I have this compile error in the first Swift line:

`'Int' is not convertible to 'AnyObject'`

Comment: You need to use `NSNumber` instead of `Int` for the generic argument, as in Objective-C only classes can be used as generic arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you instantiated it in Objective-C++, not Objective-C.

Since templates are expanded at compile-time, there is no way to consume them directly from any language not based on C++.